# change value of a line in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to change the value of a line within an array to a given string, then implode and save the data. Im using the code below.

**row** is the row of the table.
**target** is the specific line in the array which i want to update.
**nfv** is the new string i want to put into the array.

```
<?
$rowpre = $_GET['row'];
$newfieldvalue = $_GET['nfv'];
$row = --$rowpre;
$data = file_get_contents("temp.php");
$csvpre = explode("###", $data);
$i = 0;
    foreach ( $csvpre AS $key => $value){
        $i++;
        if($i = $row){
            $info = explode("%%", $value);
            $j = 0;
                foreach ( $info as $key => $value ){ 
                    $j++;
                    if($j == $target){
                        /*change the value of this line to $newfieldvalue*/
                    }
                }   
        }           
    }

$presave = implode("%%", $info);
$save = implode("###", $presave);
$fh = fopen("temp.php", 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $save);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize that you can *index into an array?* If you already have the numeric index of an array element, just go ahead and change it:

```
$arr[$index] = "some new stuff";
```

Magically updated.

Comment: so after i explode info, i could do a $info[$target] = "new stuff"; ?

Comment: You could. *Iff* I understood your code right. It doesn't actually rank high on the "tell me what you do" scale.